# C# Excel Reader turns Timestamps into a decimal number

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

When I use the Excel Reader it reads in everything fine except for time stamps. It turns, for example, 15:59:35 into .67290509259259268

How do I stop this from happening?

```
object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

That is my array that is holding the values that are read in from the excel sheet. Not sure if that is the reason.

Comment: Are you sure it's "15:59:35 into .67290509259259268" instead of 16:08:59 into that or 15:59:35 into .6663777...?

Comment: I may have misinterpreted which row it was reading in first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`DateTime.FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) - however, the numeric value you mentioned in the question doesn't actually correspond to the time you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is Excel stores all it's DateTimes as floating point numbers. The decimal part is the time component while the integer part represents the date.

You can get use [`Range.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.text%28v=office.11%29.aspx) value to get the text, which should be formatted correctly. I don't think you can use this quite in the same way as above (trying to do the same myself so not got the actual approach yet). Also be wary it might be slow reading the text (reading number formats is v.slow).

Alternatively try using a library, [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) is a very good one we use, or [Apose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) for a more complete solution.

**Itterative Approach** (this is almost certainly considerably slower than get_Value returning an object[,]).

```
if (excelRange!= null)
{
   int nRows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
   int nCols = excelRange.Columns.Count;
   for (int iRow = 1; iRow <= nRows; iRow++)
   {
      for (int iCount = 1; iCount <= nCols; iCount++)
      {
         excelRange= (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[iRow, iCount];
         String text = excelRange.Text;
      }
   }
}
```

(Edit: Removed other examples that were actually for Sharepoint.)

Comment: Thanks You. Now I at least have a place to start.

Comment: Unfortunately those libraries aren't free, but FlexCel is pretty cheap and v.easy to use. If I find a solution in Excel I'll post it.

Comment: You weren't kidding about Range.Text taking a long time. For 1800 rows w/ 59 Cols it took almost 2 minutes to run through it all.